# Compare year with date('Y-m-d') in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have dateformate list like this in mysql

```
--------------------------
born_form   |   born_to
--------------------------
1994-10-04  |  2012-05-13
1987-05-03  |  2010-03-25
```

and i have input as 1999 only year

and i m using sql query

```
Select * from table_name where
"1999" BETWEEN born_from AND born_to
```

but its not working

Comment: What do you mean "I have input as 1999 only year"

Comment: @Smamatti: what is "wrong" in the original query so that you think your proposal fixes that issue?

Comment: @Smamatti: `BETWEEN` operates with **expressions**. So it is `expr1 BETWEEN expr2 AND expr3` and expression can be a constant value, column, some mathematical expression or whatever else the expression is. While `1999` is never was a correct **date**. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between --- found it by searching `mysql between`, you're surprised? ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for correcting me. I removed my first comment to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use `YEAR()` ([see documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)) and do it like this:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table_name
WHERE
  1999 BETWEEN YEAR(born_from) AND YEAR(born_to)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
   Select * from table_name where
    year(born_from)>=1999 AND year(born_to)<=1999
```

Comment: There  is no index value
what about 'BETWEEN'

Comment: If index is as concern, just convert 1999 become date 1999-1-1 and 1999-12-31 for comparing

Comment: @bitoshi.n: I cannot imagine any case when index is not recommended to use :-S

Comment: @bitoshi.n: that doesn't matter actually already, because OP anyway has chosen the one that contains the magic `BETWEEN` word ;-) (+1 for solidarity)

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from table_name
where born_to >= '1999-01-01' AND born_from <= '1999-12-31'
```

This query in comparison to another answers **may** use indexes

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
      Select * from table_name where "1999" BETWEEN YEAR(born_from) AND YEAR(born_to)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a [example](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/between.php)

select * from table_name where year(born_from)>1999 and year(born_to)<=1999

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this,

Select * from table_name where
"1999" BETWEEN YEAR(born_from) AND YEAR(born_to)